# hook_node_presave() fires twice when adding a new node

Tags: entities, nodes

In a custom module I use `hook_node_presave($node)` on node objects with referenced fields.

When creating a new node, `ddebug_backtrace()` shows that `entity_save` is called first and then `node_save`. Which leads to two new nodes. At the end of `hook_node_presave()` I have one correctly created node and one with only partially filled fields.

How can I prevent `node_save` to fire in `hook_node_presave()` when `entity_save` was already executed? Or maybe the solution is to prevent `entity_save` to fire?

Could anybody please explain how to correctly use `hook_node_presave()` on node objects with attached referenced fields?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody else experiences the same strange problem. In my case the reason was module [CER](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) (Corresponding Entity References) 7.x-3.0-alpha7. For any reason after a complete uninstall and clean reinstall hook_node_presave() now works fine with entity referenced fields.